# Using external library with React to play .ogg files in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, ogg

Good evening. 
I'm trying to implement playing ogg-opus audio in react app in Safari (it doesn't support .ogg format). I use create-react-app to init the project.

I've found "ogv.js" library, that is actually helps to play audio files in almost all modern browsers. But can't actually get it work (https://github.com/brion/ogv.js/issues/525).

I'm requring in the top of my `PlayerComponent.js` file after all the imports

```
var ogv = require('ogv');
```

After that in my `play()` function (it's being called from `onClick` event of a button) I'm trying to play an ogg file, that I'm recieving from API:

```
play = () => {
   var player = new OGVPlayer();
   var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.props.audioData)]);
   player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   player.play();
}
```

I'm getting the below error:

> ogv-demuxer-ogg-wasm.js?version=1.6.0-20190226222001-c4648f0:1
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ogv.js:1586 Uncaught TypeError:
>   n[e] is not a function at classWrapper (ogv.js:1586) at ogv.js:4593 at
>   ogv.js:1590 at ogv.js:207 at Array.forEach () at
>   HTMLScriptElement.done (ogv.js:206)

Probably the problem is that some library files and especially 'ogv-demuxer-ogg-wasm.js' can't be loaded properly.

Any help would be helpful, maybe someone has a solution to play .ogg files in Safari in other way. Thanks!

**[UPDATED]**
Solution found, check it down below.

Comment: Hey OP, welcome to SO. Please read through the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and include a specific [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that isn't working.

Comment: my fault, added not working code!

Comment: @AliceAlice How do you show the audio controls with this? For play/pause. I've also asked a question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970499/angular-ogv-js-audio-player-controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so if anyone would ever want to play in React app .ogg/opus audio in Safari, here is the solution (using [ogv.js](https://github.com/brion/ogv.js) library).

First of all, put the library files to your React app.
For the opus you will need:

- ogv-demuxer-ogg.js
- ogv-demuxer-ogg-wasm.js
- ogv-demuxer-ogg-wasm.wasm
- ogv-decoder-audio-opus.js
- ogv-decoder-audio-opus-wasm.js
- ogv-decoder-audio-opus-wasm.wasm
- ogv-worker-audio.js

After that in your code:

Require the lib after all imports:

```
var ogv = require('ogv');
```

Set the base path for the files from the [PUBLIC](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) folder:

```
// process.env.PUBLIC_URL simply a ref for the root folder of the react app
ogv.OGVLoader.base = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/ogv';
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
play = () => {
   var player = new OGVPlayer();
   // this.props.audioData just some audio data
   var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.props.audioData)]);
   player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   player.play();
}
```

This player has some similar to default HTML5 Audio abilities, for more you can check it in the link above.

Maybe not the best solution, but at least it works :)

Comment: How do you show the audio controls with this? For play/pause. I've also asked a question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970499/angular-ogv-js-audio-player-controls

Comment: Will this work for react native app?