# Angular ogv.js audio player controls

Tags: angular, html5-audio, ogg, opus

I'm using [ogv.js](https://github.com/brion/ogv.js) in Angular 8. I want to play ogg audio in my browser (Safari).

In the browser, just the audio is being played without any controls (play/pause etc.)?

My component ts file has:

```
  const ogv = require('ogv');

  @ViewChild('ogvContainer', { static: true }) ogvContainer: ElementRef;

  ogv.OGVLoader.base = '../../assets/js/ogv';
  let player = new ogv.OGVPlayer();
  this.ogvContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(player);
  let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(decodedData)]);
  player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  player.play();
```

My component html has:

```
 <div class="ogvContainer" #ogvContainer></div>
```

Inside the ogvContainer div, another element is created.

```
<ogvjs class="ogvjs1" src="blob:http://localhost:4200/681e9637-5f93-4a0c-929e-678dd5e71529"> 
   <canvas style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain;"></canvas>
</ogvjs>
```

But nothing is displayed. It just consumes empty space.
How can I show the player controls on UI?

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information such as what are you trying to attempt exactly and a working example in plunkr.io or stackblitz?

Comment: @ZetaPR I want to show audio controls such play/pause etc. Currently, no controls are shown

Comment: Could you provide us at least with your component and template so we can see what are you trying?

Comment: @ZetaPR I'm fetching ogg data from server. That is the `decodedData` in the code above. I want to play ogg audio in Safari browser. For that I'm using ogv.js library. But the library does not seem to show any audio controls. The above code is in my component.

Comment: I understand what are you doing, but without a template I cannot help you. You will have different files .component.ts and .component.html, you need to provide us with both of this to help you

Comment: @ZetaPR The .component.html is empty. I don't know what to add there. Even if I have an audio tag there, I don't know what to assign to the src of that audio

Answer (score 0):

In order to have controls appear in the template of the component you would need to add the following line:

```
containerElement.appendChild(player);
```

The `containerElement` will be any that you create in your template

What appendChild does it to create the player in your template as explained in the ogv.js documentation

Comment: I've updated the question. Still nothing is displayed